# Perl's waitpid() and IPC::Open2 in Windows vs. Linux/UNIX

Tags: windows, linux, perl, ipc

The following code works flawlessly in Linux, but when I put it on a Windows machine, all hell breaks loose:

```
$pid = open2($my_reader, $my_writer, "$JAVACALL $PARSER_CP $PARSER_CMD -");
$my_reader->autoflush(1);
$my_writer->autoflush(1);
print $my_writer "$line\n";
close($my_writer);
my $tree = <$my_reader>;
chomp($tree);
push @parse_trees, $tree;
close($my_reader);
waitpid($pid, 0);
```

In Windows, it just hangs waiting on `waitpid($pid, 0)`.  If we comment that line out, everything finishes properly, but then we're left with numerous orphaned processes.  What confuses me is that ActiveState (who's Perl we are using) actually [says](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.14/lib/IPC/Open2.html) to do things exactly how we're doing them.

Does anyone know a Windows-happy way to do this?  Even if I have to maintain two separate versions of the code, I could care less at this point. :)

(For those curious, this code opens the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), which takes a file as input (hence the use of "-" (similar to/same as `/dev/stdin` in Linux)), throws a sentence at it, and gets back a parse tree.  Not important but I know someone is going to ask. :) )

Comment: This might be an issue: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#waitpid

Comment: What Windows version do you have? I used that approach on Win XP without problems.

Comment: Since you say you're getting orphaned processes if you leave out that line, presumably the subprocesses are not exiting and that's the problem you need to diagnose.  Perhaps Perl is issuing LF at end of line and Java is expected CRLF, or vice versa?

Comment: @squiguy Yeah, I did see that.  I've been trying to come up with a way to use system()/etc in place of the pipes, but I need a connection between my process and that process' STDIN.

Comment: @pmod Really?  We have Windows Server 2008 r2.  I'd be interested in what you did exactly if you're ok with sharing (and if it's at all different from what I did).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hmmm...I wouldn't be surprised if that was it, actually.  Windows could be blocking waiting for the CR, whereas Linux was thrilled with just the LF.  I'll try that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those who are curious, I got things working the way they should, but I'm not too crazy about part of the fix.  I added

```
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
```

and changed that `waitpid()` call to

```
waitpid($pid, &WNOHANG);
```

This alone didn't do it, so immediately after this I added

```
kill(-9, ($pid));
```

to kill the process.  Not really liking the call to `kill()` but it works, and oddly enough I still had zombie processes if I didn't also call `waitpid()`.  Again, it'd be great if anyone knows a more elegant solution, but this will have to do for now. :)